# How to write a WCF Service for SharePoint 2013 hosted App?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, web-services

I've deployed a WCF Service in SharePoint. I am able to retrieve data from it using URL:

`http://nit-hv8-itr4:1111/_vti_bin/PresidentsService.svc/GetAllPresidents`

The problem occurs when I try to access this same service through REST from SharePoint hosted App saying - ***PresidentsService.svc is not accessible from the context of a SharePoint App.***

---

I also tried changing the URL of Service as follows:

`http://apps-a6d8c7c05a0ab7.spappsitr4.com:1111/_vti_bin/PresidentsService.svc/GetAllPresidents`

Here I get error saying - ***The endpoint /_vti_bin/presidentsservice.svc is not accessible in the context of a SharePoint App.***

Comment: Are you using sharepoint online or on premise.

Comment: @Aanchal It's on premise.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the fact that SharePoint only allows out of the box REST & CSOM endpoints consumption from Apps so if you deploy custom WCF services, it won't be allowed from within the App.

If you use sp.webrequestinfo cross-domain library, you'll notice that it will work providing your service is consumable anonymously but what if you have your own service that requires authentication. Remember that in the context of a SharePoint-Hosted App, your only ways to consume web services are:
with JavaScript
using an External Content Type but that only works for data services and I'm not sure that it works if your service requires authentication
So, given the above, one way to achieve our goal is to use CORS but it will require some extra efforts before it works.

So to enable CORS in sharepoint hosted apps you can check:

http://www.silver-it.com/node/159

Comment: I referred the link you gave, i'm confused about where to add the HTTP Module, would it be my service.svc.cs?